# It's possible to match all ocurrences of a pattern inside string, with a given start and end?

Tags: regex

I need to get

```
first="john"
second="doe"
```

and

```
firstz="johnz"
secondz="doez"
```

from this text:

```
any text here [link first="john" second="doe"] anytexthere [link firstz="johnz" secondz="doez"]
```

The pattern need to get the **[link** in the start, and the **]** in the end, and can have multiples properties inside...

```
[link first="john" second="doe"] ✅ -> first="john", second="doe"
[lin first="john" second="doe" ❌
[link first="john second="doe"] ❌
[linksecond="doe"] ❌
```

Obs: "first", "john", "second", "doe" can be anything.

This is my best try:
https://regex101.com/r/cJnYIF/1

```
\[link (\w+="\w+")\]
```

But this only capture the first

I've also tried with positive lookbehind, but without success
https://regex101.com/r/jnk6gM/397

Someone have idea how to solve this? If possible XD

Comment: You need to use a positive lookbehind. But positive lookbehinds aren't allowed to use quantifiers, so it won't work.

Comment: Best one for this are .NET regex and PyPi Python regex libraries where you have access to all captures of each group. In PCRE, you may use [`(?:\G(?!\A)|\[link)\s+(\w+)="(\w+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/jnk6gM/398)

Comment: Thank you guys, GalAbre answer was a good way to solve my problem :D
I think my idea of getting params as groups is not possible directly, but the @WiktorStribiżew it could have been a way if I were using these languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/jnk6gM/399), which will match all your parameters:

```
\[link ((?:\w+="\w+" ?)+)\]
```

Then you can parse them using a `split(' ')` function, depending on the language you use.

Comment: This really helps, thank you! :D